# Once packaged, module1 cannot "import module2" from the same project

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

My project have the following structure:

```
project/
  + setup.py
  + bobafett/
    + __init__.py
    + __main__.py
    + foo.py
```

With:

- `__init__.py`: an empty file
- `foo.py`: contains the definition of `bar`:

```
def bar():
    print("foo.bar()")
```

- `__main__.py` import and use `foo.bar`:

```
import foo
foo.bar()
```

#### ✓  Locally, all works well:

```sh
~/project $ python3 bobafett/__main__.py
foo.bar()
```

#### ✗ Once `bobafett` is packaged, published and installed, `foo` is no longer found

```sh
~/project $ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
~/project $ curl -T ... https://my-pypi.example.com/simple/bobafett/...
~/project $ cd /tmp
/tmp $ pip --index-url https://my-pypi.example.com/simple --user bobafett
/tmp $ python -m bobafett
...
  File "/home/ysc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bobafett/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

How is that? What can I write instead of `import foo` that both works locally and once deployed? Do I need to change my project structure?

---

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='bobafett',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='YSC',
    author_email='ysc@example.com',
    packages=['bobafett'],
    url='https:///my-pypi.example.com/simple/bobafett/',
    description='Prints "foo.bar()".',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. change `import foo` to `from . import foo`. It will fix running `python -m bobafett` but break `python3 bobafett/__main__.py`.
2. run locally the same way as when packaged: `python -m bobafett` instead of `python3 bobafett/__main__.py`.

Comment: It works indeed :) If you happen to know why and explain it, I could accept your answer. If not, I'll wait a bit to allow others to answer.

Comment: @YSC I am not 100% sure, but combining these two answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/9609843 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11537218/9609843 gives the following: running `python3 bobafett/__main__.py` allows Python to find `foo` with `import foo` because it searches `the directory that the entry-point script is running from`. But when running from `/tmp` Python cant do it. Thus we change to `from . import foo`. After that `When you execute a file directly, it doesn't have its usual name, but has "__main__" as its name instead. So relative imports don't work.` So change to `python -m`